# Getting "no matching provisioning profiles found:

Tags: ios

I have set up a bot for continuous integration of the mobile app.
When i am running a bot, i am getting error:

no matching provisioning profiles found:your build settings specify a provisioning profile with UUID:,however no such provisioning profiles were found:
Codesign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'.

When i am building through CMD-B, it is building fine but when i am running bot, i am getting above error.
Could you please guide me as to where i am going wrong.
I am very new to Mac,iOS and Bot.

Thanks
Abhishek Somani

Comment: Your bot is running on the same Mac on which you develop ?

Comment: Hi Philippe...Thanks for the response though i am late to see that. However, i could resolve the above error but now there is other which is troubling me since 3 months...and that is 'Code signing operation failed'. Earlier when i used to run bot..it used to create 2 files for me..one archive and on ipa...but one fine day it starts throwing this warning and does not create ipa now. I have tried installing xcode on 3 different mac machines but same error. Looks like certifcate issue but when checked that..its expiry date is in 2018. I am completely out of ideas now.

Comment: I suggest that you add your own answer to this question with the solution you found, and accept this answer. Then open a new question for your 2nd problem. Place a link here so eventually I'll see it and take a look. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Philippe....i have checked in my code with the correct profile and put that profile in the following location: ~/Library/Xcode/MobileDevices/ProvisioningProfile. and then tried to build the code..it worked for me.